# wso2 esb transport vfs, read xml file with Doctype fails

Tags: wso2, esb, vfs, wso2-esb

I have a WSO2ESB 4.7 proxy with vfs transport. I need to read some xml files like this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE Header PUBLIC "/usr/xxx.dtd" "/usr/xxx.dtd">
<Header xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
...
```

Proxy:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="test" statistics="disable" trace="disable" transports="vfs">
    <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">5</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">C:\WSO2</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">.*[.][xX][mM][lL]$</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">application/xml</parameter>
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
            <log level="full"/>
            <send>
                <endpoint>
                    ...
                </endpoint>
            </send>
        </inSequence>
    </target>
</proxy>
```

Wso2 returns this error:

```
[2013-10-15 11:23:03,670] ERROR - VFSTransportListener Error processing File URI : file:///C:/WSO2/1_CHRG_2713540.XML
org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DOCTYPE is not allowed
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMDocumentImpl.getOMDocumentElement(OMDocumentImpl.java:109)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:570)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:566)
    at org.apache.axis2.builder.ApplicationXMLBuilder.processDocument(ApplicationXMLBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.processFile(VFSTransportListener.java:574)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.scanFileOrDirectory(VFSTransportListener.java:324)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.poll(VFSTransportListener.java:158)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.poll(VFSTransportListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractPollingTransportListener$1$1.run(AbstractPollingTransportListener.java:67)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DOCTYPE is not allowed
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.next(DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.java:36)
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:681)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214)
    ... 13 more
```

Is there a possibility to get wso2 ignoring the Doctype?

I dont want to read the file as text/plain, remove doctype, convert to xml, work with it, convert to text/plain, add doctype.

Comment: Above mentioned configuration works fine and I have tested it. With "application/xml" you should able to read the above input file without a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following parameter as well to the proxy service. Then it will allow DOCTYPE declaration

```
<parameter name="ApplicationXMLBuilder.allowDTD">true</parameter>
```